# Reading numbers into grid

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numbers grid, that looks like this and goes on for a while further.

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
```

I saved this grid in a .txt file assigned it to a file variable like so:

```
grid = open("grid.txt"  )

print(grid.readlines())

grid.close()
```

When I print out the contents of grid with `grid.readlines()` some problems pop up: Firstly, it is saved as a list of long string(i.e. every line is one list entry, secondly, there is the newline sign `\n` at the end of every list entry. Lastly, to convert this data into a numpy array as the grid it is, numbers can't start with a zero. I.e. 02 in the first row second column should be 2.

I'm pretty new to numpy. Is there any way to convert this data into a numpy array that would save me all the legwork of manually implementing an edited version into my code?
The only python read possibilites I know of are of csv or excel files.

Best of days to all of you :)

Comment: Check: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: `np.array([[int(x) for x in line.rstrip().split(" ")] for line in lines])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

1. Make sure you are using `open()` with the keyword `with`. Reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.

2. You can use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to achieve this.

---

```py
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

print(lines)
```

Outputs:

```
['08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08', '49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00', '81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65', '52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91', '22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80', '24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50', '32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70', '67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21', '24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72', '21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95']
```

---

```py
import numpy as np

file = np.loadtxt('file.txt')
print(file)
```

```
array([[ 8.,  2., 22., 97., 38., 15.,  0., 40.,  0., 75.,  4.,  5.,  7.,
        78., 52., 12., 50., 77., 91.,  8.],
       [49., 49., 99., 40., 17., 81., 18., 57., 60., 87., 17., 40., 98.,
        43., 69., 48.,  4., 56., 62.,  0.],
       [81., 49., 31., 73., 55., 79., 14., 29., 93., 71., 40., 67., 53.,
        88., 30.,  3., 49., 13., 36., 65.],
       [52., 70., 95., 23.,  4., 60., 11., 42., 69., 24., 68., 56.,  1.,
        32., 56., 71., 37.,  2., 36., 91.],
       [22., 31., 16., 71., 51., 67., 63., 89., 41., 92., 36., 54., 22.,
        40., 40., 28., 66., 33., 13., 80.],
       [24., 47., 32., 60., 99.,  3., 45.,  2., 44., 75., 33., 53., 78.,
        36., 84., 20., 35., 17., 12., 50.],
       [32., 98., 81., 28., 64., 23., 67., 10., 26., 38., 40., 67., 59.,
        54., 70., 66., 18., 38., 64., 70.],
       [67., 26., 20., 68.,  2., 62., 12., 20., 95., 63., 94., 39., 63.,
         8., 40., 91., 66., 49., 94., 21.],
       [24., 55., 58.,  5., 66., 73., 99., 26., 97., 17., 78., 78., 96.,
        83., 14., 88., 34., 89., 63., 72.],
       [21., 36., 23.,  9., 75.,  0., 76., 44., 20., 45., 35., 14.,  0.,
        61., 33., 97., 34., 31., 33., 95.]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Concerning with and open, I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.read_csv()` like so:

```
my_array = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=' ', engine='python', header=None).values
```

Yields:

```
[[ 8  2 22 97 38 15  0 40  0 75  4  5  7 78 52 12 50 77 91  8]
 [49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48  4 56 62  0]
 [81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30  3 49 13 36 65]
 [52 70 95 23  4 60 11 42 69 24 68 56  1 32 56 71 37  2 36 91]
 [22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80]
 [24 47 32 60 99  3 45  2 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50]
 [32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70]
 [67 26 20 68  2 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63  8 40 91 66 49 94 21]
 [24 55 58  5 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72]
 [21 36 23  9 75  0 76 44 20 45 35 14  0 61 33 97 34 31 33 95]]
```

Comment: thank you! I sadly can only accept one answer, but this is super helpful as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use solely *Numpy*, without resorting to *Pandas*.
The code to do it is:

```
tbl = np.fromfile('Input.txt', sep=' ', dtype='i4').reshape(-1, 20)
```

No need to drop the leading zeroes on your own. *Numpy* does it for you.